# Pointers vs references C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have been slowly but surely working through LearnCpp.com chapters learning C++.  I have a lingering confusion over distinguishing a pointer vs a reference to a variable.

Here is an example:

[code]

```
Fraction& Fraction::operator= (const Fraction &fraction)
{
    // self-assignment guard
    if (this == &fraction)
        return *this;

    // do the copy
    m_numerator = fraction.m_numerator;
    m_denominator = fraction.m_denominator;

    // return the existing object so we can chain this operator
    return *this;
}
```

[/code]

So this function to overload operator=, does it return an address to a fraction, or a reference to a fraction?

by returning *this at the end of the function, is that a give away that means it's an address?  Also, I thought "*this" was a de-reference and would result in the actual data being pointed to.  So does it return an address, or the actual data pointed to?

Lastly, in the "self assignment guard" if statement (this==&fraction), I always read "&" in the parameter list as "a reference to" the variable.  But that statement is comparing it to "this" which is a pointer variable.  So is it a pointer ("&fraction") or an address?  Does including the "&" in the **body** of the function mean the data being pointed to?

Please clarify these issues.  It really would help me a lot.  Thanks.

Dean.

Comment: "I have been slowly but surely working through LearnCpp.com" - this may be your problem - that is not a great resource.

Comment: There are no known good (or even half decent) online C++ tutorials. Invest in a good book.

Comment: Well, there are flaws in everything, but please focus on answering the question.

Comment: @deanc2000 -- *but please focus on answering the question* -- The comment section is for comments, the answer section is for answers.  That's the way it works here.  The comments made to you are where they should be placed -- in this section.

Comment: A portion of us don't take kindly to someone asking something that is trivially answered by a good book, advising to get one is already on the kinder side. You being dismissive and ignoring them isn't going to help.

Answer (score 0):

> So this function to overload operator=, does it return an address to a fraction, or a reference to a fraction?

It returns a *reference to a `Fraction`*. The beginning of a function (or an operator) is supposed to be a *return type* (ignore `template`s for now). Here we can see `Fraction&`, which is a *reference to a `Fraction`*.

> by returning *this at the end of the function, is that a give away that means it's an address?

Returning `*this` means that the function is returning what's pointed by `this` pointer. It's literally *this* object. Given the fact that the return type is a *reference*, the opereator will return a reference to *this very object*. It does not return any addresses.

> I always read "&" in the parameter list as "a reference to" the variable

You really shouldn't. `&`, combined with *variables* (not *types*) is an **address-of** operator. In this case:

```
if (this == &fraction)
```

it checks if *this very object* (the one pointed to by `this` pointer) is the same object as passed to the function as `fraction` argument. `fraction` is a reference, which means that its address will be the same as the address of the object that reference is bind to. This effectively checks *if you tried to assign an object to itself* (given the fact that this code is executed in assignment operator).